# Programmer Dvorak on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I have recently learned that there is a modified version of the Dvorak keyboard layout called 'Programmer Dvorak'. It is not in the list of choices on Mac OS X. Is it possible to install it?

Comment: // , It is not available on El Capitan, either, from what I've seen, and the packages provided by the Programmer Dvorak maintainer are all for previous releases: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220749/how-do-i-set-up-the-programmer-dvorak-key-layout-on-el-capitan

Comment: @nathan-basanese: Please don't over-generalize: Programmer Dvorak has been available for El Capitan practically since that version was released. Just because it doesn't show up in the keyboard selector before reboot doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely be able to create it with [**Ukelele**](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=Ukelele&_sc=1).

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed possible to create your own layout with Ukelele. However, it has already been done, so why not [simply download the .keylayout file](http://homepage.mac.com/thgewecke/tckbs.html) ?

Note : To install a new keyboard layout from a .keylayout file, simply drop the .keylayout file in your ~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/ directory (or in  /Library/Keyboard Layouts/ for a system-wide install).

Comment: Please notice that on 10.6 you need to restart every app after you install the new layout, and on 10.3 you need to actually logout and login again, IIRC (don't know about 10.4 and 10.5).

Comment: // , Does this work on El Capitan? If so, would you be willing to add an answer to my question about Programmer Dvorak?

Answer (score 3):

You must download an extension module from the [Programmer Dvorak home page](http://kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/#downloads).

Comment: Key combinations like ⌃A don't currently work with it, but you can fix it by [editing the keylayout file](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75117).

Comment: // , As of 20160107, this does not work for Mac OSX - El Capitan: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220749/how-do-i-set-up-the-programmer-dvorak-key-layout-on-el-capitan

Comment: @nathan-basanese Please don't over-generalize: I have tested this on El Capitan